What is the maximum disk size for a RAID controller?
Do RAID controllers have a limitation in maximum size of the single physical disk?
I have a venerable ARC-1220 controller with 2 TB disks in JBOD mode and I am considering expanding it by replacing the disks with 8 TB models.
I didn't find a specification about the maximum supported disk size, so did I overlook something or maybe my RAID controller and possibly RAID controllers in general can handle disks of any size?

In general : there certainly are limits to the size of disks that certain RAID controllers can and/or will support. For example IIRC the PERC 6 has a limit of 2TB.

I can't find any description of the SATA interface chips on that card, though it rhapsodizes the Intel IOP for its ability to handle RAID 6 in hardware. I do see in the manual, however, where it specifies "Greater than 2TB capacity per disk drive support". As 2TB is one of the boundaries where disk capacity can be a problem, I believe that you're all right with 8TB disks.

The chip is the Intel IOP333 SATA2 I/O processor from around 2008. There's probably no limit on the card. Could be a limit on the host. https://www.scribd.com/document/87080423/Datasheet

Intel, in their documents for their board-level IOP333 solution, shows controller chips of some sort between the IOP333 and the actual SAS sockets, so I didn't want to leap to any conclusions about what the respective duties and limitations were.
